# gmm function in R does not work due to singular variance-covariance matrix

Tags: r, finance, generalized-moments

We want to test the [CAPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_asset_pricing_model) asset pricing models using the GMM procedure. The model is as follows:
$$ R_{i,t} - R_{f,t} = \alpha_i + \beta_i(R_{m,t} - R_{f,t}) + \epsilon_{it}$$
The pricing errors at time $t$ can be expressed as a $(N+F)K\times 1$ vector of moment functions as follows:
$$
e(z_t,\theta) =
\begin{bmatrix}
R_t^e - R_t^e(f_t - \mu_f)'b\\
f_t - \mu_f
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes Z_t
$$
where $\theta = (b',\mu_f')'$ is a $2F\times 1$ vector of parameters, $Z_t$ is a $K\times 1$ vector of instruments, $f_t$ is a $F\times 1$ vector of factors, $R_t^e$ is a $N\times 1$ vector of excess returns and $z_t=(R_t^{e'}, f_t', Z_t')'$ stacks all the variables.

Therefore, since we have $1$ explanatory variable ($F$), 4 instruments ($K$), 18 countries ($N$), this should become a $76\times 1$ vector for each time $t$.
Hence, as we have a total of $122$ observations, our function `g` to use in `gmm()` correctly produces a $122\times 76$ matrix.

The following code represents our function that produces the matrix

```r
g <- function(theta,data){
 CAPM_GMM <- matrix(NA,ncol = 122, nrow = 76) 
 beta <- theta[1]
 mu_f <- theta[2]
for (t in 1:122){
  Re <- data[t,1:18]
  ft <- data[t,19]
  Zt <- data[t,20:23] 
  pricingerror_pt2_l <- ft-mu_f
  rhs <- Re - Re * (pricingerror_pt2_l*beta)
  e <- matrix(NA,ncol = 1, nrow = 19)
  e[1:18,1] <- rhs
  e[19,1] <- pricingerror_pt2_l
  pricingerror <- kronecker(e, Zt)
  CAPM_GMM[,t] <- pricingerror
  }
  CAPM_GMM <<- CAPM_GMM
 return(CAPM_GMM)
}

t0 <- c(0.5,-0.5)

gmm(g,x=data,t0=t0)
```

The problem occurs when trying to run the gmm() function as it keeps giving the error:

> model order:  1 singularities in the computation of the projection
> matrix results are only valid up to model order 0Error in AA %*% t(X)
> : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments.

Also another error has occured stating that it cannot be computed since it is singular

Also when using an identity matrix as a weights matrix produces this error. For somehow, whatever we do, it keeps returning a determinant of zero of the variance covariance matrix of the matrix CAPM_GMM such that gmm does not work in our case. Hence, it might be an error in the function `g()`.

Below I will give a short insight of the data (the whole data sheet is $122\times23$). The countries represent the excess returns. The column without a name is the $R_{m,t}-R_f$ from the CAPM model. And the final four represent the IV represented as $Z_t$ in the vector of moment functions.

[image: Data]

Comment: take a look at: http://www6.uis.no/ansatt/odegaard/teach/notes/gmm_estimation_capm/lecture_gmm_estimation_capm.pdf

Comment: If you want an answer it would be very helpful to include a [mcve] of your data, if such a thing is possible, ideally using `dput` to include the actual data, not just an image.